# Levenshtein distance between list of number

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance

Have this code , i want to have levenshtein distance between two list of numbers.

```
import textdistance
S1=[1,2,3,7,9,15,19,20]
S2=[1,2,3,7,8,14,20]
#convert lists to string 
Str1=‘’.join(str(e) for e in S1)
Str2=‘’.join(str(e) for e in S2)
textdistance.levenshtein.similarity(Str1,Str2)
textdistance.levenshtein.distance(Str1,Str2)
```

The above code gives similarity of : 7 
Which is wrong , the correct is 5  .
And shows distance value of 4 , which wrong also, the correct distance is 3.

How to manipulate the code so that numbers like 14 and 15 can be seen as one element to the function above ? Any idea ..

Comment: Would not using `distance` instead of `similarity` work?

Comment: @Drecker if it worked with similarity it will work with distance . Distance gives me 4 , which is wrong too. The correct distance is 3 .

Comment: @Drecker I updated the code above and added distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pip install textdistance
```

Do not convert to the string, keep the code as is:

```
S1=[1,2,3,7,9,15,19,20]
S2=[1,2,3,7,8,14,20]

textdistance.levenshtein.similarity(S1,S2)
textdistance.levenshtein.distance(S1,S2)
```

Comment: After removing convert to string , the code worked in juypter Notebook , but in visual studio 2017 , it gives me am error says” sequence item():expected str instance，int found” .

Comment: `textdistance.levenshtein.distance` was what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jellyfish library as such:

```
import jellyfish
S1=[1,2,3,7,9,15,19,20]
S2=[1,2,3,7,8,14,20]
#convert lists to string 
Str1=‘’.join(str(e) for e in S1)
Str2=‘’.join(str(e) for e in S2)

jellyfish.levenshtein_distance(Str1, Str2)
```

You may find more info about it here: https://pypi.org/project/jellyfish/

Comment: This has the same issue as the library he is using.  Converting the 2-digit numbers to strings results in a 2-digit string.